# Laravel 4 with vagrant database migration "using password NO" reset

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, vagrant

I am currently getting an error when I do my database migration with artisan with the command

```
 sudo php artisan migration
```

I then get the following error:

```
 SQLSTATE[28000][1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).
```

I don't know where I would be able to reset the password or how and I have been looking for quite some time now. Any advice would be great. I am running this in a vagrant box. Thank you.

Comment: Did you edit your `app/config/database.php` file?

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly where I needed to put the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `app/config/database.php` file

Comment: i edited and i tested on cmd mysql , it says access denied but i can do it without a problem from mysql command :(